# Apache Drill Embedded installed, but not able to run query on windows

Tags: apache-drill

I've installed the latest version of Apache drill (embedded mode) on my own desktop Windows 7, following the instructions on their website : //drill.apache.org/docs/drill-in-10-minutes/. Launched the command line and typed sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local" and looked like I've had drill up and running. Below are the results of the command prompt.

> c:\apache-drill\bin>sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
>
> DRILL_ARGS - " -u jdbc:drill:zk=local"
>
> HADOOP_HOME not detected...
>
> HBASE_HOME not detected...
>
> Calculating Drill classpath...
>
> Oct 03, 2018 6:06:44 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler
>   initialize
>
> INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.8 2014-04-29
>   01:25:26...
>
> apache drill 1.14.0
>
> "got drill?"
>
> 0: jdbc:drill:zk=local>

But when I tried a simple query showing databases, it just returned dots. Tried some other simple queries like SELECT * FROM dfs.`C:/drill/apache-drill-1.14.0/sample-data/region.parquet`，also returned a line of dots.

> c:\apache-drill\bin>sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
>
> DRILL_ARGS - " -u jdbc:drill:zk=local"
>
> HADOOP_HOME not detected...
>
> HBASE_HOME not detected...
>
> Calculating Drill classpath...
>
> Oct 03, 2018 6:06:44 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler
>   initialize
>
> INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.8 2014-04-29
>   01:25:26...
>
> apache drill 1.14.0
>
> "got drill?"
>
> 0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> show databases
>
> . . . . . . . . . . . >

Also it didn't work when I tried to launch the web console. Can someone help me troubleshooting this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify semicolon in the end of line ;)

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> show databases;
+---------------------+
|     SCHEMA_NAME     |
+---------------------+
| cp.default          |
| dfs.default         |
| dfs.root            |
| dfs.tmp             |
| information_schema  |
| sys                 |
+---------------------+
6 rows selected (0.099 seconds)
```

Comment: It worked! I'm a newbie to Drill so didn't realize a semicolon is needed for the query. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It could help you:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/query-data-introduction/#query-syntax-tips